# PHP Remove index position of both arrays in a multidimensional array are null

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, output

If I have an array like so:

```
    array:2 [▼
      "LAST NAME" => array:3 [▼
        0 => "RAY"
        1 => null
        2 => "TERRIER"
      ]
      "HOBBY" => array:3 [▼
        0 => "PIANO"
        1 => null
        2 => "BASKETBALL"
      ]
    ]
```

My desired result:

```
    RAY|PIANO
    TERRIER|BASKETBALL
```

How can I remove both index 1 of my multidimensional array while making sure that a multidimensional array that only has **one** inner array with a null index is still kept? 
So if I have an array like this:

```
    array:2 [▼
      "LAST NAME" => array:3 [▼
        0 => "RAY"
        1 => null
        2 => "TERRIER"
      ]
      "HOBBY" => array:3 [▼
        0 => "PIANO"
        1 => "SKATING"
        2 => "BASKETBALL"
      ]
    ]
```

It will return:

```
    RAY|PIANO
    |SKATING
    TERRIER|BASKETBALL
```

Thanks!

**Edit:**
This is what I have but I believe it removes anything that contains a null:

```
        $h2 = '';
        foreach ($tempArray as $key => $value){
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($value); $i++){
                if(is_null($value[$i])){
                    $i++;
                }
                $h2 .= implode($delimiter, array_column($tempArray, $i))."\n";
            }
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What were the results?

Comment: I've tried the following but I believe this just gets rid of my record even if one array index is null:
$h2 = '';
        foreach ($tempArray as $key => $value){
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($value); $i++){
                if(is_null($value[$i])){
                    $i++;
                }
                $h2 .= implode($delimiter, array_column($tempArray, $i))."\n";
            }
            break;
        }

Comment: Is that an expected result: `RAY|PIANO
    |SKATING
    TERRIER|BASKETBALL` ?

Comment: Yes that is an expected result if possible, if it is completely null I would like to avoid a line with just "|" and return the other two records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it I have done the following:

- grouped subarray items together (mergedValues variable), after it looks like this:
  `[ 0 => ["RAY", "PIANO"], 1 => [null, null]...]`
- filtered out the arrays containing only nulls (the cutNulls variable)
- produced final string

  ```
  <?php

  $input = [
      "LAST NAME" => [
          0 => "RAY",
          1 => null,
          2 => "TERRIER",
          3 => null
      ],
      "HOBBY" => [
          0 => "PIANO",
          1 => null,
          2 => "BASKETBALL",
          3 => "TENNIS"
      ]
  ];

  $mergedValues = array_reduce(
      $input,
      function (array $out, array $in) {
          foreach ($in as $key => $value) {
              $out[$key][] = $value;
          }
          return $out;
      },
      []
  );

  $cutNulls = array_filter(
      $mergedValues,
      function (array $vals) {
          return !empty(array_filter($vals));
      }
  );

  $finalString = array_reduce(
      $cutNulls,
      function (string $out, array $values) {
          return $out .= implode("|", $values) . "\n";
      },
      ""
  );

  echo $finalString;
  ```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) function.  The command is:

```
array array_combine ( array $keys , array $values )
```

The values of the $keys array become keys to the values in $values. For example:

```
cholmes@felix:~/project$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > $m = array(0=>"thing1", 1=>null, 2=>"thing3");
php > $n = array(0=>"apples", 1=>"dull", 2=>"klog");
php > $l = array_combine($m, $n);
php > var_dump($l);
array(3) {
  ["thing1"]=>
  string(6) "apples"
  [""]=>
  string(4) "dull"
  ["thing3"]=>
  string(4) "klog"
}
```

Two items to note here:

- Using null as a key results in an empty string `""`
- The command assumes you're using numbered arrays.  I haven't explored what happens when you use associative inputs, or if some indexes are missing.